# Advance search in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Advance search in angular js for more than one filed dependent on click event not working ..I want to perform search on multiple column and send only one request to search by clicking search buttton ,not by sending request every time when i type on input fields.

```
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("<?php echo 'process.php';?>")
  .then(function(response) {
     $scope.prospectsList = response.data;
  });

   $scope.searchTable = function(){
    $scope.searchParam = $scope.search ; 
  }

 });
</script>


<tr>
    <th align="center"><input type="text" ng-model="search.fname"/></th>
    <th align="center"><input type="text" ng-model="search.lname"/></th>
    <th align="center"><input type="text" ng-model="search.email"/></th>
    <th align="center"><input type="submit" ng-model="searchList" ng-click ="searchTable();" value='Search'/> </th>
</tr>

<tr dir-paginate = "data in prospectsList |filter:searchParam|itemsPerPage:10" >
    <th align="center"> {{data.first_name}} </th>
    <th align="center"> {{data.last_name}} </th>
    <th align="center"> {{data.email}} </th>
    <th align="center"> {{data.country}} </th>

</tr>
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean, exactly?

Comment: What happens when you click on "Search" button? And what do you mean when you say it's not working? You haven't done anything inside the search method to make it work!

Comment: You assign the same object, so everytime you change the input fields the filter changes. Instead do this: `$scope.searchParam = angular.copy($scope.search);`

Answer (score 3):

**Requirement:**

*send only one request to search by clicking search buttton ,not by sending request every time when i type on input fields.*

HEre is your required solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div ng-controller="MyController" class="my-controller">

          <p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

          <input type="text" ng-model="search.first_name" />
          <input type="text" ng-model="search.last_name" />
          <input type="text" ng-model="search.email" />
          <input type="submit" ng-model="searchList" ng-click="searchTable();" value='Search' />
          <ul>
            <li dir-paginate="data in prospectsList |filter: searchParam | itemsPerPage: 2">
              {{data.first_name}} {{data.last_name}} {{data.email}} {{data.country}}
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div ng-controller="OtherController" class="other-controller">
            <div class="text-center">
              <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("<?php echo 'process.php';?>")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.prospectsList = response.data;
    });

    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.searchParam ={};
    $scope.searchTable = function(){
    $scope.searchParam = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.search)); 
    }
    $scope.prospectsList=[{ first_name: "111",last_name: "222",email: "333", country: "casdasda"},{ first_name: "777", last_name: "888",email: "gfgdf", country: "casdasda"},{ first_name: "test", last_name: "555",email: "gfgdf", country: "casdasda"}];

 });
```

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9pH0UAKHuHbXHyJjGy82?p=preview)